# Multi Dimensional Array Assignment from Dataset

Tags: vb.net, arrays, dataset, multidimensional-array

I am attempting something along the line of below mentioned code. Though it works in single dimension array. How to make it work with 2-d array?

```
Dim arrayord(,) As String = {ds.Tables(0).Rows(3).ItemArray, ds.Tables(0).Rows(23).ItemArray}
```

But it throws the following error.

*Error 8 Value of type '1-dimensional array of 1-dimensional array of Object' cannot be converted to '2-dimensional array of String' because '1-dimensional array of Object' is not derived from 'String'.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim dtb1 As New DataTable("Table1")
dtb1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column1", GetType(Integer)))
dtb1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column2", GetType(Integer)))
dtb1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column3", GetType(Single)))
dtb1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column4", GetType(String)))
dtb1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column5", GetType(String)))
dtb1.Rows.Add(1, 1, 1.1, "1", "5")
dtb1.Rows.Add(2, 2, 2.2, "2", "4")
dtb1.Rows.Add(3, 3, 3.3, "3", "3")
dtb1.Rows.Add(4, 4, 4.4, "4", "2")
dtb1.Rows.Add(5, 5, 5.5, "5", "1")
dtb1.Rows.Add(11, 11, 11, "11", "11")

Dim strOutput(dtb1.Rows.Count - 1, dtb1.Columns.Count - 1) As String '(row,col)
For intRow As Integer = 0 To dtb1.Rows.Count - 1
  For intCol As Integer = 0 To dtb1.Columns.Count - 1
    strOutput(intRow, intCol) = CStr(dtb1.Rows(intRow).Item(intCol))
  Next intCol
Next intRow
```

Or you could use a List(Of String()) instead of a two dimensional array:

```
Dim lstOutput As New List(Of Object()) From {dtb1.Rows(0).ItemArray, dtb1.Rows(1).ItemArray, dtb1.Rows(2).ItemArray}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of this method but I am looking for a solution without looping through the datatable/dataset

Comment: Why don't you want to loop? (Also, why not just use the dataset instead of an array)

Comment: (I'm unaware of any way to convert a series of 1-dimensional arrays to a 2-dimensional array without using a loop)